# Justifying a line of text from user input (C++)

Tags: c++, string, justify

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string line;
    const int SIZE = 75;
    int punct_index = 0;
    int whitespace_index = 0;
    
    cout << "Input Line: " << endl;

    getline(cin, line);

    while (line.find_first_of(".,!?;", punct_index) != string::npos)
    {
        punct_index = line.find_first_of(".,!?;", punct_index);
        line.insert(punct_index + 1, " ");
        punct_index++;
    }

    while (line.size() < SIZE)
    {
        int rand_index = (rand() % SIZE) + 1;
        whitespace_index = line.find(" ", rand_index);
        if (whitespace_index != line.size() - 1)
        {
            line.insert(whitespace_index + 1, " ");
        }
    }
    cout << "Your line justified is: "<< endl;
    cout << line << endl;

}
```

I'm having some trouble with the spacing in the code provided above.
This is what my output for the prompt I am given:

```
Input Line:
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
Your line justified is:
Contrary  to popular  belief,   Lorem  Ipsum is   not  simply random text.
```

What it should look like

```
Input Line:
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
Your line justified is:
Contrary to  popular belief,   Lorem Ipsum  is not   simply  random    text.
```

What I am trying to do is to put one (1) space after the punctuation marks to get to the value 75 (which is how many characters are supposed to be in that line) and then add spacing to random words in the same line to get to 75.

The spacing is slightly off, but I don't know where it goes wrong when debugging. The first thing that I noticed was the first instance of a space is skipped over in the correct version, but is noticed by my version. So I naturally think "Oh, I have to either make a variable -1 somewhere or just decrement the `whitespace_index`." Neither one worked so I was very confused. I went to look at what my professor showed us and his second while loop uses `line.size() > SIZE`. When I use it, that entire block of code gets skipped entirely. 
What it looks like:

```
Input Line:
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
Your line justified is:
Contrary to popular belief,  Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
```

Notice the extra space at the end of the line (after the period).
I honestly don't know what goes wrong, but I have tried debugging the code to see and I don't know where the code decides to just do pretty close to the opposite of what I need. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong because it seems like a very simple fix and I think I'm just overlooking it.

Comment: Your actual ouptut is 75 characters. Your expected output is 77 characters. You say you should be "add[ing] spacing to random words in the same line to get to 75." Can you explain why your expected has 77 characters while your actual ("incorrect") output has 75?

Comment: I know right? It doesn't make sense to me either, but apparently that is the correct output and my code is technically incorrect.

Comment: If your output matches your algorithm, the issue is not with your code. It's with your understanding of the problem. Which we can't help you with. This is a question for whoever gave you the problem and the "correct" output.

Comment: The length of the final [string is `75`](https://ideone.com/wP1pgS). What's the issue?

Comment: The issue is that I either don’t fully understand the question I’m asked or my professor has the wrong output.

Comment: I agree with scohe001: state your problem formally, then write the code for an algorithm solving that problem. Personally I find both outputs horrible. I'd prefer to justify the line as `Contrary  to  popular  belief,  Lorem  Ipsum  is  not  simply  random  text.` if 76 slots were available.

Comment: And as `Contrary  to  popular  belief,  Lorem  Ipsum is  not  simply  random  text.` if 75 was the desired length.

Comment: Your algorithm is strange: you are inserting spaces after punctuation marks with no checks for going over the justified length. Your randomization can insert multiple spaces into the same location, which is [likely] wrong.